# excel 2007 - shortcuts to jump back to the previous cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

Anyone know of any shortcuts to jump back to the previous cell that you were in, other then ctrl+g. I need to use that in vba.

Any tips or ideas would be appreciated...stuck with another issue and this could help.

thanks

Comment: "stuck with another issue and this could help" – Please make sure there's no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/355310) here.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to place the Cell Pointer to the *"LAST USED CELL"* then use this VBA Code line.**

```
Private Sub Move_to_Last_usedCell_Click()

ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select

End Sub
```

I think this was the reason "**jump back to the previous cell**", I've posted different VBA code to move Cell Pointer to Previous Cell/Row in my my First Solution.

*Hope, this help you and others too.*

Comment: This brings my cursor down the page to a cell I wasn't in just like when I use last cell in the go to function.

Comment: I am trying to clear the values copied after they were pasted in another cell. I can add clear.selection at the bottom of the vba but it clears the new cell pasted into instead of the old one copied.  For example

Comment: @ReneBourgoin, You can use this Code line also,,                             EndRow = Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count+1, _
      ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @ReneBourgoin,, Last Cell depend on many factors like Save the file & reopen changes the Last cell, some times Last blank cell ect.

Comment: @ Rajesh S,, thanks for all the help Rajesh, nothing really seems to work yet but it is still very appreciated.  EndRow = Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count+1, _ ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row turns red for some reason in the vba.

Comment: @ Rajesh S,,  1 question that should be very easy for you :-)  how can you enter your codes so it look so neat in these text boxes.  I tried to copy paste my codes but it looks like a mess when I enter it here.  Even a printscreen would work.  Haven't really found an answer in *learn more about formating*

Comment: @ Rajesh S,,  Maybe a simpler question would be, is there a way I can cut values only and paste values only so it doesn't effect any of the formatting in the page?